# DELL 7370/Ubuntu 18.04 virtual terminal problem

Tags: uefi, dell, authentication

Last November(2018) I bought a DELL 13 7370 laptop and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it without problems.  I used the Virtual Terminals periodically when I wanted to avoid the GUI and had no problems. Last week I decided to reinstall using UEFI rather than BIOS.  I did so with no apparent problems except for the fact that none of the VTs will accept my login.  The screen looks fine, asks for my name, accepts that and asks for my password. After I enter it and the system says my logon in invalid.  I'm the only one that uses this machine and my password works fine for everything else, including root login.

I'm puzzled.  Anyone have any suggestions

Comment: Did you change any other configurations besides the boot mode? Maybe full disk encryption, home encryption, keyboard layout, language?

Comment: When you say "root login", do you mean `sudo su` or `sudo -i`? Asking cause logging in as root is not recommended.

Comment: wjandrea:   I changed nothing that I know of other than boot mode.  Keyboard layout is fine.  No encryption involved. Any version of root login works from the GUI.  I mentioned it only to show that my password was OK.